# When submitting a form, variables get update, but don't renew in the textarea

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, textarea

Excuse me for the title, it was a bit hard to explain my problem. So here it is. On http://appsolute.vacau.com/cms I have a variable in the textarea. You see the output of the variable from start. Updating the text en submitting the form IS updating the variable. Thus far everything is right, right? On submitting the form, the page is reloaded, but all the content is from the previous content of the variable. But when checking, the variable WAS updated. Even if you refresh the page. 
So why don't I get to see the actual value of the variable after submitting the form?
Hope it makes sense...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Milan CMS</title><?php
$host     = "x";
$dbname   = "x";
$username = "x";
$password = "x";
$dbh      = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$sth      = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM milan   ");
$sth->execute();
$result   = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        var_dump($result);
        $myFile   = "trainingen.json";
        $fh       = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, json_encode($result));
        fclose($fh);
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="trainingen">
            <h3>Trainingen:</h3><p><textarea name="nametrainingen" rows="10" cols="60"><?php echo $result[0]['value']; ?></textarea></p>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Verzenden"><input type="reset" value="Veld leeg maken">
        </form>
        <?php
        $invoer   = $_POST['nametrainingen'];
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //test if submit button is clicked
            $sql = "DELETE FROM milan WHERE tag = 'trainingen'";
            $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO milan (tag, value) VALUES ('trainingen', '$invoer')";
            $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute();
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you maybe want to switch what order you do stuff, now its: 1. load old data, 2. prentate old date, 3. add new data, I usaly handle the _POST data first, before presentation of data, so when i do the fetch, the new data is alredy stored in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re-arrange the logic like so:

```
<?php
        $invoer   = $_POST['nametrainingen'];
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //test if submit button is clicked
            $sql = "DELETE FROM milan WHERE tag = 'trainingen'";
            $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO milan (tag, value) VALUES ('trainingen', '$invoer')";
            $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute();
        }

        $sth      = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM milan   ");
        $sth->execute();
        $result   = $sth->fetchAll();
    ?>
       <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="trainingen">
            <h3>Trainingen:</h3><p><textarea name="nametrainingen" rows="10" cols="60"><?php echo $result[0]['value']; ?></textarea></p>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Verzenden"><input type="reset" value="Veld leeg maken">
        </form>
```

Comment: Made one more change, for the select - it should work now. Check my updated answer

Comment: @Raidenance, thank you... It works... New to all this, but it works like a charm...

Comment: Glad it worked for you :-) Also pay heed to what Peter Szymkowski mentioned: you have to do database `delete` & `update` before doing `select`, in order to fetch the latest data.

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic. First make changes to DB

```
DELETE FROM milan
INSERT INTO milan
```

then load rows from DB

```
SELECT * FROM milan
```

Comment: did this 2, still weird behaviour... Played around with coding on different ways... It keeps giving the same behaviour, thats 1 of the reasons for my header text, thought that might help. Both suggestions are online atm.

Comment: Thank you Peter, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to process your data before you output stuff. This means that you have to follow a certain procedure:

- load core configuration: database connection etc.
- insert / update tables and fill / preset variables
- select stuff from the (now updated) database
- output (most likely html)